# Add or remove a class when a class has been added to a parent div

Tags: jquery

I need to add or remove a class if a parent div has a class which has been added dinamically. I tryed this, but only works when I click. I need to detect if a class has been added even if I don´t click it. So, the question is: how to execute the function when the class is added, not when you click?

```
$(".accordion > .fa").click(function(){ 
if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up');
    $(this).addClass('fa-angle-down');
}
else
{
   $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-down');
   $(this).addClass('fa-angle-up');
}
});
```

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Use $(this).parent("active"). And you should use click function selector as $(".accordion  .fa"). Remove unnecessary ">" from selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.accordion').each(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
            $(this).children('.fa').addClass('fa-angle-down');
        }else{
           $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
           $(this).children('.fa').addClass('fa-angle-up');
        };
});
```

This code needs to be run as a callback function for the event that sets/unsets the .accordion element.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cop5uybb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this).parent("active"). And you should use click function selector as $(".accordion .fa"). Remove unnecessary ">" from selector. Javascript code would be like following.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".accordion  .fa").click(function(){ 

if ($(this).parent("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up');
    $(this).addClass('fa-angle-down');
}
else
{
   $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-down');
   $(this).addClass('fa-angle-up');
}
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Perhaps I was not clear, the question is: how to execute the function when the class is added. Not when you click. Thank you anyway